# OneSignal UserID Is Returning Nil - swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, onesignal

In my app, I have setup a notification system using OneSignal and Firebase. However, when I prompt the OneSignal Notification Alert and the user allows notifications, the userID/playerID returns nil. Here is the following code:

```
static func getNotificationPermissionsAndStorePlayerIdInFireabse(currentUserId: String) {
    OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification
    OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
        if accepted == true {
            let status: OSPermissionSubscriptionState = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState()

            let userID = status.subscriptionStatus.userId
            let pushToken = status.subscriptionStatus.pushToken

            if pushToken != nil {
                if let playerID = userID {
                    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserId).child("oneSignal").setValue([playerID: pushToken!])
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

In the code above I access the userID and push token, however, the userID returns nil. The push token, on the other hand, has a value. I don't know why the userId is nil. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: Please note I call this function after my user logs in.

Comment: try printing userID maybe value is not being added there and try printing your [ status.subscriptionStatus.userId  ] too

Comment: its printing nil

Comment: both printing nil ?

Answer (score 0):

What version of OneSignal do you have? I have an app that uses OneSignal but I use different function to access user's OneSignal ID: (I actually couldn't find function you are using)

```
OneSignal.idsAvailable({ (userId: String?, registrationId: String?) 
  // Check for ID
  if let onesignalUserId = userId {
    // Save OneSignalId to Firebase
  }
})
```

Comment: I have the latest version and in that version the function ids available is deprecated.